# Is "town" a countable noun?

Tags: countability

Is the noun "town" a countable or uncountable noun? Since the plural of "town" is "towns" it seems it is a countable noun.

On google it said that is countable and uncountable. Here is a link https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/town.

Comment: Hello Isaac.  I assume you've looked this up in a dictionary and found it is countable.  What is the doubt here?  Why do you think the dictionary is wrong?

Comment: On google it said that is countable and uncountable and that is why I got confused.

Comment: Quote the part where "Google" says that "town" is uncountable. Add it to the question and include the link. I will upvote the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many (or even most) nouns, the word town can be used as a countable or an uncountable noun.

As a countable noun you might say:

> I live in a town called Smallville.

> There are five major towns in my county.

As an uncountable noun, meaning "land with houses, in contrast to countryside"

> Do you prefer life in town or on a farm?

It also has a sense which is grammatically uncountable, meaning "This town" or "the local major town".  In this sense it is like a proper noun.

> I'm going to town on Sunday.

> This is the best hotel in town.

Compare this with "I'm going to school." It is an institutional uncountable noun.

So, in English, some nouns are usually countable, some nouns are usually uncountable, and some nouns have both countable and uncountable uses. In particular certain nouns can be used as uncountable nouns when they refer to an institution.  "School" and "Town" are examples of this type of noun.

Comment: A person from a rural location might go to an urban location, and look out of the hotel window and say "I see town all around."